# Convergence of series of functions: $f_n(x)=u_n\sin(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, fourier-series

> Let $f_n(x)=u_n\sin(nx)$  where $\displaystyle\sum f_n$  converges pointwise, and $ \displaystyle x \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} f_n(x)$ is continuous.
>
> Prove that $ u_n\rightarrow 0$ when n tends to $+\infty$

My 'attempt':

We know that  $S_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_k\sin(kx)$ converges to a real $a$, and 
$$
S_{n+1}-S_n=u_{n+1}sin((n+1)x) 
$$
converges to $0$.
By induction we can prove that for all $x=(\frac{\pi}2)^k$ then $u_n$ tends to $0$.

I really don't know how can I continue.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: This is probably a sledgehammer: If $f$ is the limit function, then the  $u_n$ are the Fourier $\sin$ coefficients of $f$. Since $f$ is continuous, these tend to $0$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks but I don't understand why $u_n$ are necessarily the fourier sin coefficients of f ?

Comment: $f$ is integrable on finite intervals (presumably). I may be misremembering, but I think this implies that if $f$ is expressed as a trigonometric sum, then that sum must be the Fourier series for $f$.

Comment: @DavidMitra In fact, it works only if the convergence is uniform

Comment: The result in my last comment "if a trigonometric series converges everywhere to  an integrable function $f$, then it is the Fourier series of $f$" is more general than that. It can be found in  Zygmund's *Trigonometric Series*, Theorem IX 3.1. The proof of this doesn't seem easy; I would guess  your problem admits a relatively simple solution. What results have you seen so far?

Comment: @DavidMitra Ah ok thank you, I will check the result.   I have seen the lesson about Series of function, Fourier-series : trigonometric polynomials,  Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, Bessel inequalities, Dirichlet's theorem, Weirstress theorem..I hope this will address your question.

Comment: @DavidMitra http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/mon/mon05/mon0504.pdf
I don't see where is your theorem :/

Comment: That's not it. It's in Zygmund's monograph "Trigonometric Series", Volume 1, page 326. But, it turns out your problem is a version, with a much stronger hypothesis, of the Cantor-Lebesgue lemma. See 4.2 of  [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.iitb.ac.in%2Fatm%2Fafs106%2Fkesavan.pdf&ei=kDwGU-TZHOjo0wGzyIHIDA&usg=AFQjCNFOQO-fdc_5P0kPLUtDLunciSSAiw&bvm=bv.61725948,d.dmQ&cad=rja). Perhaps the proof there will give you some ideas.

Comment: @DavidMitra Nice, I will work on it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler than my comments above indicate.

All you need is that the sum converges pointwise  on a non-degenerate interval $[a,b]$ (in fact, all you need is that the sum converges on a set of positive measure; see my last comment above). Assume this is the case.

Suppose $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} u_n\ne0$. Choose $\delta>0$ and a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ such that $|u_{n_k}|>\delta$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$.

Note we must have 
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}u_k\sin(k x)= 0\ \text{ for all }\ x\in[a,b]\tag{1}$$

Given any closed interval $I\subset [a,b]$,
 we can find $n_k$ with $k$ as large as desired and $n_k|I|>2\pi$. With $n_k$ selected as such, we can find a closed subinterval of $J$ of $I$ so that $ \sin(n_k x)>1/2$ for all $x\in J$.

Using this, we  inductively find a sequence of closed intervals $[a,b]\supset I_1\supset I_2\supset\cdots$ and positive integers $n_1<n_2<\cdots$ such that
$$
|u_{n_k}|\sin(n_kx)\ge \delta/2\tag{2}
$$
for $x\in I_k$, $k\in \Bbb N$.

The set $I=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ is non-empty.  Pick $x\in I$. Then $x\in[a,b]$  and satisfies $(2)$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$.  But this contradicts $(1)$.

It follows that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} u_n=0$.

(I don't see how to obtain a simpler proof that takes advantage of your stronger hypothesis.)

Comment: Wah! It's excellent. Thank you very much.